# JAVAFX: Adapter-Like View for a Gantt Chart?

Tags: java, android, javafx, android-adapter, gantt-chart

Android had this thing called an Adapter, which loaded only 5 or so items on screen out of the 100 available as you scrolled through the list of videos/images/etc. I am currently building a Gantt chart, but it is highly efficient.

My current method is to fill out all 365 days and work from there, but as you know, this is far too intensive.

I was thinking of coding it so that only 30 days (or however many cells there are on screen) are shown at a time. As you scroll left or right, it recycles the cells, discarding the off-screen data, and filling in with the on-screen data instead.

Is this too complicated?

My other thought was to fill out only the first and last days of each month instead of all 365 days. That way, I only have 12 cells with data. I have to calculate the cells in between manually.

What would be the best thing for me to do?

Comment: Your suggested solution is a very high-performing one, but it will be hard to implement. This is basically the way JavaFX implements `ListView`, `TableView` etc behind the scenes (these are called "virtualized controls"). You might want to read through the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/java/javafx/scene/control) to those. Also have a look at Tomas Mikula's [Flowless](http://tomasmikula.github.io/blog/2014/07/06/richtextfx-just-got-faster.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am also implementing a calendar panel which has infinite scrolling. One solution obtained from many sources is that you use a canvas with scrolling listener.
When user stop scrolling, you redraw that part of the ganttchart.

With the data model, you can cache data for custom ranges to improve performance.